# Rebol SOAP Server

Tags: rebol

Where can I find the source of the soap server in rebol mentioned here:
http://www.rebolplanet.com/zine/rzine-1-02/#sect6.

the link http://www.compkarori.co.nz/reb/discordian.txt doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have this sort of question, try pasting the URL into the search box of archive.org (The Internet Archive).

In this case, a copy of the file was snapshotted in 2004:

http://web.archive.org/web/20040205210622/http://www.compkarori.co.nz/reb/discordian.txt

*(You might let the operators of the site know the %reb/ directory is missing, since the others in the set are still there.)*

Comment: Thanks, I will think about it next time.

Answer (score 2):

It's also now in my GitHub repo

https://github.com/gchiu/Rebol2/blob/master/Scripts/discordian.r

Comment: Hi Graham, I tested it by calling from a Visual Studio program it doesn't work any idea ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757695/webservice-works-with-soapsonar-but-not-with-visual-studio-winform